# Select output from multiple aggregate functions returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following SQL statement, why does it return multiple rows with the correct count instead of one row?

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.table t WHERE t.column IS NULL
  ) AS t_Inserts,
   (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.table t WHERE t.column IS NOT NULL
  ) AS t_Updates
FROM
  schema.table t;
```

Note: I'm using Oracle.

```
Output:
t_Inserts,t_Updates
100,200
100,200
100,200
100,200
100,200
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you posted runs the `t_Inserts` subquery (and the `t_Updates` subquery) once for every row in `schema.table`.  Since you're querying `schema.table` with no `WHERE` clause, the result set must have as many rows as `schema.table` has.  If you want a single row, you could `SELECT` from the `dual` table

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.table t WHERE t.column IS NULL
  ) AS t_Inserts,
   (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.table t WHERE t.column IS NOT NULL
  ) AS t_Updates
FROM
  dual
```

It would probably be more efficient, though, to do something like

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN t.column IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) t_inserts,
       SUM( CASE WHEN t.column IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) t_updates
  FROM schema.table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Justin's answer (+1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)-COUNT(column) AS t_Inserts, COUNT(column) AS t_Updates
FROM schema.table;
```